# Improve the structure of this Angular filter solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a filter mechanism on checkboxes to display a list of items, modified from an example about wine. I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing in terms of basic code structure that would make this solution a lot easier to understand (i.e. structure), especially around the filter check and the DOM in case I'm not using filters the way they are supposed to be used or if there is something I can do to eliminate lines of code.

[**JS Fiddle HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr99vwcy/1/)

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <b>Category:</b>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
        <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[cat]" /> {{cat}}</b>
    </div>
    <hr />
    Popularity
    <div ng-repeat="w in filtered=(wines | filter:filterByCategory)">
        {{w.name}} ({{w.categories}})
    </div>
    <hr />
    Number of results: {{filtered.length}}
</div>
```

...

```
$scope.filterByCategory = function (wine) {
      if (!$.isEmptyObject($scope.filter)) {
          var checkThisArray = wine.categories;
          for (var i = 0; i < checkThisArray.length; i++) {
              if ($scope.filter.hasOwnProperty(checkThisArray[i])) {
                  if($scope.filter[checkThisArray[i]]) {
                      return true;  
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return noFilter($scope.filter);
};
```

Comment: You could do this with something like underscope or lodash in far fewer lines of code.

Comment: You don't need line 
if ($scope.filter.hasOwnProperty(checkThisArray[i]))
because next line returns undefined if $scope.filter hasn't got checkThisArray[i] key.